# boot ubuntu from dvd - terminal

Tags: boot, dual-boot, unity, dvd

I have a small problem on one of my laptop's, my unity desktop is not working and I can not login into my home screen, now I have tried everything and now I want to install new version of `ubuntu`.

I can enter my laptop using `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F3`, and question is, how can I boot from `dvd` so I can install fresh version of `ubuntu`?
Simple terms how to boot from `dvd` from `terminal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't boot from a running system (the terminal).  You boot by having the boot media attached and select it as the boot drive.  In this case it will be the option to boot to the DVD.

Make sure you have the DVD placed in the computer.  When you boot the computer, you'll see keys to hit to enter the bios option or the boot drive.  You can also check your computer's manual for the option to enter the BIOS and set the boot drive.

Comment: yea, I just figure that out,  when I wrote this question (facepalm)